# Calling a CCViewController from a CCLayer

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I'm very new to cocos2d so sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm making a cocos2d game which is made up of different CCLayers. I swap between the layers by calling their scene methods. I want to call a CCViewController from a button on one of the layers but since a View Controller doesn't have a scene method, i don't know how to do this. I've tried research it and theres a lot of mention about Storyboards but I'm not too familiar with them and my project doesn't have one. Can anyone help? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to put cocos2d view in your own view and control it from your view controllers. Of course, you can do it without Storyboards.

Actually, `CCDirectorIOS` is a subclass of `UIViewController`. So you can add its view to any of your own `UIView`s.

In my code, I do it like this:

```
CCDirectorIOS *director = (CCDirectorIOS *)[CCDirector sharedDirector];
...
UINavigationController *navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director];
navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;
navController_.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
...
[self.view addSubview:navController_.view];
...
```

Next, you can trigger UIButton event to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry but I am very new to all this so I don't quite understand what you mean. I have minimal experience with view controllers. Could you rephrase it in terms of the layer and the view controller in question if that makes sense? Cheers :)